# Is using a 8-pin connector for 12-pin ATX 12V power connector ok?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer, computer-building

My motherboard supports a 8+4-pin CPU power but my power supply only has the 8pin connector wire. Is this ok or do I need to buy another power supply to support the additional 4-pin?

Answer (score 0):

> Is using a 8-pin connector for 12-pin ATX 12V power connector ok?

Yes

> do I need to buy another power supply to support the additional 4-pin?

The 4-pin connector is only required if the hardware supports it.